# How to find and stop empty PING log

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I see log message created every 0.05 seconds.

```
To: /, MessageID: urn:uuid:33b0aab6-49a7-4646-bb49-883f202ff09b, 
Direction: request, Envelope: 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

when I click on more I dont see any more info

```
     Type   Date    Log Message

        2017-06-21 08:11:34,483 To: /, MessageID: urn:uuid:33b0aab6-49a7-4646-bb49-883f202ff09b, Direction: request,
Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>  More
TID[-1234] [ESB] [2017-06-21 08:11:34,483] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /, MessageID:
urn:uuid:33b0aab6-49a7-4646-bb49-883f202ff09b, Direction: request,
Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/>   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think that this is a ping message from WSO2. Is there a way to stop this?
It is over sizing my message logs..HELP

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your ESB receive a blank http request on `/` every 0.05s

When it receive a request on a non existing proxy service, default sequence "main" is executed (and it's behavior is to call log level="full")

- Find who send this request to your ESB (monitoring probe ?)
- Change default "main" sequence (remove log mediator)
- Change defaut log4j.properties so that RollingFileAppender is used

Comment: Thank you Jean-Michel , yes you were right... something are hitting my esb every .05 sec. Right now I removed log level = "full" from main sequence to stop log messages .. Do you know easy way to found who is pinging my ESB ?

Comment: Not sure if it will give you client IP, but you can try option 1 : activate wire logs (uncomment log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG in log4j.properties). Option 2 Inside wso2 esb, you can find tcpmon (see esb_home/bin) : stop your esb or change the default port with carbon offset, launch tcpmon and create a listener on the port actually used by your ESB (8280 ?)

Answer (score 0):

It is generated by a log mediator included in your service:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Log+Mediator

You can choose log level = "custom" to customize your log. See example 2 on the above page.

Comment: jbdev, I know who created (Log Mediator) but I want to see which sequence creating it ... It is annoying  and what to stop it ....